# Unexpected behavior from Drools' collectSet and difficulty effecting undo moves

Tags: drools, optaplanner

What I *actually* wanted to do is to have a Drools rule as so:

```
rule "globalRequiredPredecessorAfterMe"
when 
    $rpAll: Set(size>1) from accumulate (
        Customer(vehicle!= null, vehicle.vehicleTyp != VehicleTyp.DUMMY, $rpAfterMe: requiredPredecessorsAfterMe);
            collectSet($rpAfterMe)
        )
then
    scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $rpAll.size()-1);
end
```

Unfortunately, on the second move in CH drools awards me with a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.drools.core.rule.SingleAccumulate.reverse(SingleAccumulate.java:124)
...
```

Is this a feature?

I swallowed my pride and to wrote a fantastically complex `Listener` which is supposed to to what the Drools rule above did. With an `assertionScoreDirectorFactory` (an `EasyScoreCalculator`) I get score corruption. On a closer look, I get a corruption in one of the two cases:

1. My planning entity's `previousXXX` is set exactly to the same value
2. An `Undo` move is done

To investigate, I set the solution to the state just before the score corruption occurs. I use the `CreateChangeMove`s from Optaplanner's 7.4.1.Final `SolutionBusiness` class. (On a side note, it would be really helpful if one could also set a `MoveCountLimit` in the SolverConfig.)

So I create the `scoreDirector` as follows

```
SolverFactory<MySolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(
            SolverConfigXML);
solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

ScoreDirectorFactory<MySolution> scoreDirectorFactory = solver.getScoreDirectorFactory();
scoreDirector = scoreDirectorFactory.buildScoreDirector();
scoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(unsolvedSolution);
```

within a `JUnit 5` test and then perform several `ChangeMoves` to mimick the solution just before the offending move occurs. However, when I perform the offending move as in bullet 1 above,

```
// customer SUK0002030's previousVehicleOrCustomer is DUMMY_3
cm = createChangeMove(nameToCustomerMap.get("SUK0002030"), "previousVehicleOrCustomer", nameToVehicleMap.get("DUMMY_3"));
cm.doMove(scoreDirector);
```

I get a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity (SUK0002030) has a variable (previousVehicleOrCustomer) with value (DUMMY_3) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextCustomer) with a value (null) which is not that entity.
Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.inverserelation.SingletonInverseVariableListener.retract(SingletonInverseVariableListener.java:87)
...
```

When I set the `previousVehicleOrCustomer` to `null`, and then back to `DUMMY_3`, everything is fine and no score corruption occurs.

Similarly, when attempting to create an (offending) `UndoMove` of the previous Move `cm`, bullet 2 above, as so

```
cm.createUndoMove(scoreDirector).doMove(scoreDirector)
```

I get the same message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity (SUK0002014) has a variable (previousVehicleOrCustomer) with value (Vehicle_0) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextCustomer) with a value (null) which is not that entity.
Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.inverserelation.SingletonInverseVariableListener.retract(SingletonInverseVariableListener.java:87)
...
```

Of course, if I manually create the `UndoMove` (by simply setting the `previousVehicleOrCustomer` back to `null`), everything is fine.

These moves really should be possible and I'm really curious to find out what's wrong.

Comment: That first exception, that NullPointerException, is clearly a bug in Drools. Please [create a jira with a reproducer](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/DROOLS).

Comment: (unless it's already fixed in a later release, because it looks familiar)

Comment: Will do.. Any idea on the other issue?